# Using System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive for zipping does not work from F# code

Tags: f#

I am trying to create a zip file from a byte array in F# with a following script. File seem to be created correctly but when I try to open it I got an error.

When I tried to unzip the byte array coming from `zipFile` function I got an `System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.`

Am i doing something wrong in the `zipFile` function?

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.IO.Compression.dll"
#endif

open System.IO
open System.IO.Compression
open System.Linq

let zipFile (fileName: string) (data: byte []) =
    try
        use ms = new MemoryStream()
        use archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create)

        let entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName)
        use entryStream = entry.Open()
        use bw = new BinaryWriter(entryStream)
        bw.Write(data)

        Ok (ms.ToArray())
    with e ->
        Error <| sprintf "Cannot zip stream %s: %s" fileName e.Message

let saveFile path fileName (data: byte []) =
    try
        use fs = File.Open(Path.Combine(path, fileName + ".zip"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Ok ()
    with e ->
        Error <| sprintf "Cannot save file %s: %s" fileName e.Message

let data = "test" |> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
let filename = "data.txt"

data
|> zipFile filename
|> Result.bind (saveFile "C:\\temp" filename)
|> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code but I would add `#r System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` to be able to access the ZipFile extension methods and I would test if explicitly closing the disposables helps you.

Comment: Does the order in which any of these streams are closed matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need finer-grained control over when the various `IDisposable` resources involved are closed, so that the `ZipArchive`'s content is fully flushed to the `MemoryStream` before you return the byte array:

```
let zipFile (fileName: string) (data: byte []) =
    try
        use ms = new MemoryStream()
        (
          use archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
          let entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName)
          use entryStream = entry.Open()
          use bw = new BinaryWriter(entryStream)
          bw.Write(data)
        )
        Ok (ms.ToArray())
    with e ->
        Error <| sprintf "Cannot zip stream %s: %s" fileName e.Message
```

You can use `(...)` parentheses to add explicit/nested scope for the `use` bindings.